# How to write a math function in LaTex

Tags: lyx

I am trying to write the following in latex.

[image]

Would anyone please suggest me the command?
Thank you.

Comment: The `\limits` primitive puts the following index below the `\max` operator. You are searching this: `$\max\limits_a Q(s_t,.)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{a}{\max Q}(  s_{t},.)
\]    
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

If you want the `a` below max only, then use

```
\[
\underset{a}{\max}Q(  s_{t},.)
\]
```

[image]

Or since `max` is already math operator (thanks to hint), `\underset` is not needed and you can just do

```
\[
\max_a Q(s_t,.)
\]
```

Comment: I have some comments: `\max` is already a math operator; `\max_a` is enough, `\underset{a}{\max}` is overly complicated. Furthermore, `\left` and `\right` are doing here nothing but messing up spacing.

Comment: @campa thanks. Made improvements. I am used to using `\left(` and `\right)`